# Doubleclicking cell / format to split cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I'm copying data written in Word documents to an Excel sheet using VBA. When I copy the data, it looks like this:

[image]

I seperate the X,Y,Z values in this cell using

```
splitvals = split(.Cell(1,1), Chr(10))
```

However, splitting only works when I first doubleclick the cell in my sheet. By doubleclicking the cell format changes and looks like this:

[image]

I tried the function wraptext, I tried recording Macro, but I don't actually now what is happening by doubleclicking and how to automize this. Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Did you try setting `Range("A1").WrapText = True` for that cell? It won't show any line breaks if this is not set to `True`.

Comment: Yes I did, no errors but also nothing happens..